# Timthumb getting error: Could not create the file cache directory

Tags: php, timthumb

Recently I am working on a project, where I need an image resizer script. I searched many times on Google, but I did not found any good script. I just saw one named **timthumb**, but I'm still getting problems.

I am using this code snippet for trimming the image:

```
<img src="trim.php?src=/ahsan.jpg&h=150&w=150"/>
```

But when I run the file, I get an error. I could not found any resized image, but just a blank page. Also, I got this error:

```
Could not create the file cache directory
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely because your file cache directory permissions do not allow TimThumb to write to it. To find your file cache directory go into the timthumb configuration file and look for "FILE_CACHE_DIRECTORY" constant.

Modify the permissions on that folder and make sure it is writable by the user executing the script

Answer (score 0):

Like **A_funs** answered, you should have the "cache" folder. If you don't have, create it on your **root** folder or **aside** your file.

I managed to solve the problem giving permission to this **cache** folder through **770** permission.